# Copy files to bin folder with .nuspec files

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuspec

I have `.nuspec` file to create my package which contains nothing but a folder with text and other format files. I pack the folder like this:

```
<files>
  <file src="myData\**\*.*" target="content" copyToOutput="true" />
</files>
```

When I install the nuget package I want this folder to be in my bin folder/output folder so that my program can relatively reference the files present. How can I achieve this since my nuget package doesn't have any `.csproj` to have `.target` file to copy files?

Comment: I cannot think of anyway but to have an empty project and a target file to copy your files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the exact answer to your question, but I am not sure if you can achieve this without a `.target` file. As a workaround, you can create an empty `.csproj` with a `.target` file which shall copy the items of your content folder:

```
<Project>
    <Target Name="CopyToDeployFolder" AfterTargets="Build">
        <Exec Command="xcopy.exe $(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\..\content $(OutputPath) /e /y /i /r" />
    </Target>
    <Target Name="CopyToPublishFolder" AfterTargets="Publish">
        <Exec Command="xcopy.exe $(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\..\content $(PublishDir) /e /y /i /r" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```